# MYSQL, multiple insert and ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I'm really blocked with multiple insert values and if any one exist, do custom update. Here is my query that not work :

```
INSERT INTO `table` (f1,f2,status) VALUES 
(1,5,'on') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='off', 
(3,2,'on') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='off', 
(15,20,'on') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='off';
```

There is any solution that can do this query?

Thanks for everyone

Comment: with custom update you want specific fields update or removing old values with new one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `ON DUPLICATE KEY` per `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(f1, f2, status)
    SELECT 1 ,5, 'on' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 2, 'on' UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 20, 'on'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = 'off';
```

(Of course, you can also do this with `VALUES`; I just prefer `SELECT` because it is more general.)

Comment: Gordon, how it's possible to add IF also? 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = 'off' IF status= 'on';

Comment: @user3308323 . . . I don't think that is necessary if `status` only takes on two values.